# How to remove rows while iterating in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

How to remove rows while iterating in numpy, as Java does:

```java
Iterator < Message > itMsg = messages.iterator();
while (itMsg.hasNext()) {
    Message m = itMsg.next();
    if (m != null) {
        itMsg.remove();
        continue;
    }
}
```

Here is my pseudo code. Remove the rows whose entries are all 0 and 1 while iterating.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np

M = np.array(
    [
        [0, 1 ,0 ,0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0], #remove this row whose entries are all 0
        [1, 1, 1, 1]  #remove this row whose entries are all 1
    ])


it = np.nditer(M, order="K", op_flags=['readwrite'])
while not it.finished :
    row = it.next()     #how to get a row?
    sumRow = np.sum(row)
    if sumRow==4 or sumRow==0 : #remove rows whose entries are all 0 and 1 as well
        #M = np.delete(M, row, axis =0)
        it.remove_axis(i)  #how to get i?
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove it during the iteration?  This could be very slow if you have a lot of removals to do, because every time you remove a row you have to do a copy.  Unless there's a very good reason, you shouldn't do this.

Comment: @DSM how about recording the index of rows what I want to remove, then remove it at the end of iterating?

Comment: @DSM, my goal is to get **a maximum permutation matrix** B from a logical matrix A, which I described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522363/get-the-maximum-permutation-matrix-from-logical-matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing good `numpy` code requires you to think in a vectorized fashion.  Not every problem has a good vectorization, but for those that do, you can write clean and fast code pretty easily.  In this case, we can decide on what rows we want to remove/keep and then use that to index into your array:

```
>>> M
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
>>> M[~((M == 0).all(1) | (M == 1).all(1))]
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

---

Step by step, we can compare `M` to something to make a boolean array:

```
>>> M == 0
array([[ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

We can use `all` to see if a row or column is all true:

```
>>> (M == 0).all(1)
array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

We can use `|` to do an `or` operation:

```
>>> (M == 0).all(1) | (M == 1).all(1)
array([False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

We can use this to select rows:

```
>>> M[(M == 0).all(1) | (M == 1).all(1)]
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

But since these are the rows we want to throw away, we can use `~` (NOT) to flip `False` and `True`:

```
>>> M[~((M == 0).all(1) | (M == 1).all(1))]
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

---

If instead we wanted to keep *columns* which weren't all `1` or all `0`, we simply need to change what axis we're working on:

```
>>> M
array([[1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
>>> M[:, ~((M == 0).all(axis=0) | (M == 1).all(axis=0))]
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

Comment: What about removing **columns** whose entries are all 0 and 1?

Comment: @QiankunSU: the argument to `all` is the axis. Replace `all(1)` with `all(axis=0)`, and then use `M[:, ~(formula)]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed step-by-step explanation. On a different vein, if we wanted to iterate through the rows of an ndarray, is it possible to delete as we go? I wonder if it will cause problems in the iteration.