# Algorithm to find largest identical-row square in matrix

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, graph-algorithm

I have a matrix of 100x100 size and need to find the largest set of rows and columns that create a square having equal rows. Example:

```
  A B C D E F               C D E 
a 0 1 2 3 4 5         a     2 3 4 
b 2 9 7 9 8 2                       
c 9 0 6 8 9 7   ==>                   
d 8 9 2 3 4 8         d     2 3 4    
e 7 2 2 3 4 5         e     2 3 4
f 0 3 6 8 7 2
```

Currently I am using this algorithm:

```
candidates = [] // element type is {rows, cols}
foreach row
    foreach col
        candidates[] = {[row], [col]}
do
    retval = candidates.first
    foreach candidates as candidate
        foreach newRow > candidates.rows.max
            foreach newCol > candidates.cols.max
                // compare matrix cells in candidate to newRow and newCol
                if (newCandidateHasEqualRows)
                    newCandidates[] = {candidate.rows+newRow, candidate.cols+newCol}
    candidates = newCandidates
while candidates.count
return retval
```

Has anyone else come across a problem similar to this? And is there a better algorithm to solve it?

Comment: What is the time complexity of your solution? Sometimes it's hard to figure out the complexity of python code for non-python coders.

Comment: Sorry, this was supposed to be pseudocode, but is probably uglier. This algorithm's worst case (and close to average) will be `O(n^4)`, pathological input is a matrix with all the same value.

Comment: Does it have to be square, or can it have different width and height?  Also I presume that `candidates[] = {[row], [col]}` really intends to *append* an item to the list, rather than set the list.

Comment: Also if I'm reading it correctly, your algorithm won't necessarily find the largest square: since you loop first on rows beyond `candidates.rows.max` when looking to add a new bottom-right corner, you always prefer to add a bottom-right corner that is as close to the top as possible, even if this corner will be far out to the right (and thus prevent further corners being added on later).  It could be that a slightly lower, but much further-to-the-left corner could be added instead, and this would allow the overall square to become larger.

Comment: Yes, there's a reduction from the NP-hard problem of finding a maximum biclique.

Comment: @j_random_hacker To clarify on my ugly pseudocode, `[]` is the append array operator. Also the `if` line does not break, so **every** one is added.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I'm having trouble seeing the connection with bipartite graphs, could you please clarify

Comment: This feels similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/29068775/2336725, but I like your idea of going from `candidates.rows.max` better.

Comment: The upshot of David's reduction is that, unfortunately, your problem is at least as hard as another problem (namely the problem of finding the maximum balanced bipartite subgraph of a bipartite graph) which is known to be NP-hard, i.e. extremely unlikely to have a polynomial-time solution.  As a side note, your algorithm is (unfortunately much) worse than O(n^4), since it iterates over *every possible set* of rows and columns that together form a square.  E.g. on a matrix with all the same value, there are n^2 + (n choose 2)^2 + (n choose 3)^2 + ... + (n choose n)^2 squares :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented a [branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) solver for this problem in C++ at http://pastebin.com/J1ipWs5b.  To my surprise, it actually solves randomly-generated puzzles of size up to 100x100 quite quickly: on one problem with each matrix cell chosen randomly from 0-9, an optimal 4x4 solution is found in about 750ms on my old laptop.  As the range of cell entries is reduced down to just 0-1, the solution times get drastically longer -- but still, at 157s (for the one problem I tried, which had an 8x8 optimal solution), this isn't terrible.  It seems to be very sensitive to the size of the optimal solution.

At any point in time, we have a partial solution consisting of a set of rows that are definitely included, and a set of rows that are definitely excluded.  (The inclusion status of the remaining rows is yet to be determined.)  First, we pick a remaining row to "try".  We try including the row; then (if necessary; see below) we try excluding it.  "Trying" here means recursively solving the corresponding subproblem.  We record the set of columns that are identical across all rows that are definitely included in the solution.  As rows are added to the partial solution, this set of columns can only shrink.

There are a couple of improvements beyond the standard B&B idea of pruning the search when we determine that we can't develop the current partial solution into a better (i.e. larger) complete solution than some complete solution we have already found:

1. A dominance rule.  If there are any rows that can be added to the current partial solution without shrinking the set of identical columns at all, then we can safely add them immediately, and we never have to consider *not* adding them.  This potentially saves a lot of branching, especially if there are many similar rows in the input.
2. We can reorder the remaining (not definitely included or definitely excluded) rows arbitrarily.  So in particular, we can always pick as the next row to consider the row that would *most* shrink the set of identical columns: this (perhaps counterintuitive) strategy has the effect of eliminating bad combinations of rows near the top of the search tree, which speeds up the search a lot.  It also happens to complement the dominance rule above, because it means that if there are ever two rows X and Y such that X preserves a strict subset of the identical columns that Y preserves, then X will be added to the solution first, which in turn means that whenever X is included, Y will be forced in by the dominance rule and we don't need to consider the possibility of including X but excluding Y.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It's always great to work on a domain-specific problem and then find out there are actual algorithms that can make it work rather than the stupid and straightforward way!

Comment: You're welcome!  B&B search is actually a general approach to solving problems, and as such it can't guarantee fast solution times -- there will be some inputs on which it will be not much better than exhaustive search (meaning it could take millions of years).  But hopefully your problem instances are not those ones!  I realise now that my code doesn't actually report the solution at the end: to do this, you could append the original row number to each row in `rows` (it's necessary to track this, as rows are swapped around), and save it and `cols` whenever a new maximum is found.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the NP-hardness reduction I mentioned, from biclique. Given a bipartite graph, make a matrix with a row for each vertex in part A and a column for each vertex in part B. For every edge that is present, put a 0 in the corresponding matrix entry. Put a unique positive integer for each other matrix entry. For all s > 1, there is a K<sub>s,s</sub> subgraph if and only if there is a square of size s (which necessarily is all zero).

Given a fixed set of rows, the optimal set of columns is easily determined. You could try the [a priori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) on sets of rows, where a set of rows is considered *frequent* iff there exist as many columns that, together with the rows, form a valid square.